# How do I refresh my winforms page?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to make a form where the user can fill in a textbox and click a button, and information about what they typed in the textbox will show up below. In my case, this is transaction history, and can possibly be very long, much longer than the page. I have a way of writing the information on the screen(Note: This is just one value of a few per element, one element per line):

```
for (int ii = 0; ii <= Quantitys.Length - 2; ii++)
{
    Controls.Add(new Label
    {
        Name = "QuantityLabel",
        Location = new Point(25, (30 * ii) + 250),
        AutoSize = true,
        Text = Quantitys[ii]
    });
}
```

I don't think the numbers and variables matter in this case, otherwise I would have specified what they were. I'm just showing you how I am printing my labels.

But I don't know how I could clear the page when the user wants something else displayed. What would be the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a grid to show this tabular data?

Comment: I imagine you would need to hold a reference to all of your dynamically created controls (perhaps in a `List<Control>` or something) and then remove them from the form.  Seems really manual, though.  I imagine a data-bound grid where you simply change its `DataSource` would be a *lot* easier.

Comment: @Yuck Thanks! I wasn't aware there was a grid control, I'm fairly new to VS. I'll try to figure out how it works, thanks!

Comment: Dynamically adding controls to a winform can easily get sloppy and unmanageable.  Just controlling visual data flow gets to be a horrendous task.  Not to mention potential memory problems.  Some of these issues are addressed in WPF, however if you can use a data view control / grid view then by all means do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put the labels inside a panel and clear the panel, when something else is wanted.

Add:

```
 panel1.Controls.Add(new Label());
```

Clear:

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
```

Better explained:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
            {
                panel1.Controls.Add(new Label
                {
                    Location = new Point(10, 10+(i*30)), 
                    Text = i.ToString()
                });

            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much easier to use a GridDataView imo

Comment: Ok, use that then, whatevet makes you happy!